# How to fix Incompatible version for pod "React native Intercom"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, intercom

I experience some problem on my react native project setting up the Intercom Messenger. I already set up those instructions given on the documentation of intercom. However I got 2 error given to me when I used the Pod Install.

> [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Intercom":
> In Podfile:
> intercom-react-native (from `../node_modules/@intercom/intercom-react-native`) was resolved to
> 3.0.0, which depends on
> Intercom (~> 12.0.0)
>
> ```
> react-native-intercom (from `../node_modules/react-native-intercom`) was resolved to 21.1.1, which
> ```
>
> depends on
> Intercom (~> 10)

Here is the code inside PodFile

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'Mobapp' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )

  pod 'react-native-intercom', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-intercom'

  target 'MobappTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  use_flipper!()

  # post_install do |installer|
  #   react_native_post_install(installer)
  #   __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  # end
end
```

Intercom Version:

```
"react-native-intercom": "^21.1.1",
"@intercom/intercom-react-native": "^3.0.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `manual` install the `react-native-intercom`, regarding the intercom integration [documentation](https://developers.intercom.com/installing-intercom/docs/react-native-installation) no worry to use Automatic linking with `cd ios & pod install` or `npx pod-install`, this library will be linked automatically as well.

so please remove this line `pod 'react-native-intercom', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-intercom'` from your `Podfile`, and try again.
It will work as well.

Confirmed with:

```
Intercom RN: "@intercom/intercom-react-native": "^3.0.5"
ReactNative: `0.66.2`
iOS: `15.5`
```

Hope this will help you.